# ElastiCache Redis Servers

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

AWS ElastiCache servers with redis come in everything from very small to very large multi cpu boxes. But redis is single threaded. Anyone know what Amazon is doing to make it use all the cores? I'm assuming that they do, otherwise it's kind of strange that they would be offering it.

Answer (score 2):

The response from AWS was that redis is indeed single threaded. But it's a good suggestion to have more than one CPU to handle OS and network chores, so that Redis gets the resources to run. This makes sense.